# How Can I change Image type with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, node-imagemagick

I need to change my Image type after Uploading. I have tried  with image_magick but failed.What is the best way to change a image type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, the best ImageMagick alternative in node.js is [`sharp`](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/), based on libvips library.

A simple usage example (convert jpeg to png):

```
const sharp = require('sharp')
// [...]
sharp('input.jpg')
.rotate()
.toFile('output.png', (err, info) => {
  console.log(info)
})
```

Docs: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/